# SPFx call a function

Tags: spfx

We have created SPFx react web part. We want to display data from SharePoint list into a grid. One of the fields is a date field. So need to format the date field. Below is the success function:

```
success: function(resultData) { 
      reactHandler.setState({ 

        items: resultData.d.results 
      });
```

And below is the div:

```
 {this.state.items.map(function(item,key){ 

             return (
              <div className={styles.rowStyle} key={key}>
                <div className={styles.CellStyle}>{item.Title}</div>
                <div className={styles.CellStyle}>{item.StartDate}</div>

              </div>); 
          })}
```

where `item.StartDate` is the date field. How to format the below date field to show data in `mm/dd/yyyy` format instead of SharePoint date format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Intl.DateTimeFormat object` to modify the date and time formats.

You can declare a function as below:

```
private formatDate = (date: string) => {
    return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { 
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'numeric',
        day: 'numeric' })
      .format(new Date(date));
};
```

After that, you can use it in your code as below by calling it:

```
this.formatDate(item.StartDate)
```

So, your code would be as below:

```
{this.state.items.map(function(item,key){ 
     return (
      <div className={styles.rowStyle} key={key}>
        <div className={styles.CellStyle}>{item.Title}</div>
        <div className={styles.CellStyle}>{this.formatDate(item.StartDate)}</div>

      </div>); 
})}
```

References - [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat)

[Intl.DateTimeFormat cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/wip/intl-datetime)

**Updated:**

```
public render() {

    // some code 
    let formatDate = (date: string) => {
        return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { 
            year: 'numeric',
            month: 'numeric',
            day: 'numeric' })
          .format(new Date(date));
    };  

    // some code    
    {this.state.items.map(function(item,key){ 
         return (
          <div className={styles.rowStyle} key={key}>
            <div className={styles.CellStyle}>{item.Title}</div>
            <div className={styles.CellStyle}>{formatDate(item.StartDate)}</div>

          </div>); 
    })}

    //some code 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. I tried above code, it shows "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatDate' of undefined" in console. Please help if I am missing anything.

Comment: Just ensure that it is present inside your component (tsx) file. I wrote this method directly inside the class and used it in the render method

Comment: Yes, it is inside the tsx file outside the render method, and called in render method.

Comment: can you check with updated code ? I have declared it inside the render method

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
{this.state.items.map(function(item,key){ 
         var sDate = new Date(item.StartDate).format("MM/dd/yyyy");
         return (
          <div className={styles.rowStyle} key={key}>
            <div className={styles.CellStyle}>{item.Title}</div>
            <div className={styles.CellStyle}>{sDate}</div>
          </div>); 
      })}
```

Comment: It gives "sDate.format("MM/dd/yyyy" as output. Considers it as text even if it is in {}

Comment: Try the edited answer.

Comment: or try this directly (worked for me):
 <div className={styles.CellStyle}>{new Date(item.StartDate).format("MM/dd/yyyy")}</div>

Comment: Thank you for the update. For me the last one also shows 'Property "format" does not exist on type "Date" '